# Vertical edge detection with convolution giving transparent image as result with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, convolution, edges, cifilter

I am currently trying to write a function which takes an image and applies a 3x3 Matrix to filter the vertical edges. For that I am using CoreImage's CIConvolution3X3 and passing the matrix used to detect vertical edges in Sobels edge detection.

Here's the code:

```
func verticalEdgeFilter() -> UIImage {
    let inputUIImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
    let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: inputUIImage)
    let context = CIContext()
    let weights: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
                              2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 
                              1.0, 0.0, -1.0]
        
    let verticalFilter = CIFilter.convolution3X3()
    verticalFilter.inputImage = inputCIImage  
    verticalFilter.weights = CIVector(values: weights, count: 9)
        
    if let output = verticalFilter.outputImage{
        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            return processedImage
        }
    }
        
    print("returning original")
    return inputUIImage
}
```

Now as a result I always get an almost fully transparent image with a 2 Pixel border like this one:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8SlA.png)

[Screenshot of the result (border on the left side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQkf.png)

Am I missing something obvious because the images are only transparent if the center value of the matrix is 0. But if I try the same kernel on some [webpage](https://www.photo-kako.com/en/convolution.cgi), it does at least lead to a usable result. Setting a bias also just crashes the whole thing which I don't understand.

I also checked Apples documentation on this, as well as the CIFilter web page but I'm not getting anywhere, so I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this or tell me an alternative way of doing this in Swift :)

Comment: Pro debug tip: add print statements everywhere. You should print the input image values and the output one ans check that the values are the expected ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying this convolution matrix to a fully opaque image will inevitably produce a fully transparent output. This is because the total sum of kernel values is 0, so after multiplying the 9 neighboring pixels and summing them up you will get 0 in the alpha component of the result. There are two ways to deal with it:

1. Make output opaque by using `settingAlphaOne(in:)` CIImage helper method.
2. Use `CIConvolutionRGB3X3` filter that leaves the alpha component alone and applies the kernel to RGB components only.

As far as the 2 pixels border, it's also expected because when the kernel is applied to the pixels at the border it still samples all 9 pixels, and some of them happen to fall outside the image boundary (exactly 2 pixels away from the border on each side). These non existent pixels contribute as transparent black pixels 0x000000.

To get rid of the border:

1. Clamp image to extent to produce infinite image where the border pixels are repeated to infinity away from the border. You can either use `CIClamp` filter or the CIImage helper function `clampedToExtent()`
2. Apply the convolution filter
3. Crop resulting image to the input image extent. You can use `cropped(to:)` CIImage helper function for it.

With these changes here is how your code could look like.

```
func verticalEdgeFilter() -> UIImage {
    let inputUIImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
    let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: inputUIImage)!
    let context = CIContext()
    let weights: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0, -1.0,
                              2.0, 0.0, -2.0,
                              1.0, 0.0, -1.0]

    let verticalFilter = CIFilter.convolution3X3()
    verticalFilter.inputImage = inputCIImage.clampedToExtent()
    verticalFilter.weights = CIVector(values: weights, count: 9)

    if var output = verticalFilter.outputImage{
        output = output
            .cropped(to: inputCIImage.extent)
            .settingAlphaOne(in: inputCIImage.extent)

        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
            return processedImage
        }
    }

    print("returning original")
    return inputUIImage
}
```

If you use `convolutionRGB3X3` instead of `convolution3X3` you don't need to do `settingAlphaOne`.

BTW, if you want to play with convolution filters as well as any other CIFilter out of 250, check this app out that I just published: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filter-magic/id1594986951